# Read and save multiple lines from text document Java

Tags: java, text

I am working on a small project to read a text document and save the contents to a database. At the moment my program is working with one little flaw. It reads the text document and puts it in the database but when there are multiple lines I would like to have multiple inserts. Each line should be a new insert(all the lines have the same structure) I use tags to the information for example 35=8 I use multiple ifs to get just the 8 but identify it with the tag 35= etc. Here is the code I have so far.

```
 public class insert5 {

public static Properties loadPropertiesFile() throws Exception {
    //
    //declaring prop object
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    // reading properties file
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("jdbc.properties");
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();
    return prop;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("create jdbc connection using properties file");

    Connection con = null;
    Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // use try becuase it tends to fail sometimes and we want error messages

    try {

        //load properties file we have created
        Properties prop = loadPropertiesFile();

        //declare vars and get the properties at the same time
        String driverClass = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.driver");
        String url = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.url");
        String username = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.username");
        String password = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.password");


        // have to instance driver
        Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance();

        // make connection object using the previous things as parameters
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        //this if is to verify the connection
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("connection created successfully using properties file");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(" unable to create connection");
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Desktop\\pruebasx.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Read line from file.
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            // Split line on space.
            String[] parts = line.split("");
            //part in parts
            for (String part : parts) {

                //part is the element in this case each fix tag with value
                array1.add(part);

            }


        }

        System.out.println(array1);


        reader.close();

        //creating the statement(should check to use prepared statement in the future

        // fecha recp y fecha sentra in query and for and ? and order
         String query = " insert into FRONTMC.HECHO (folio_hecho, folio_orden, emisora, serie,"
                + "clave_sentido, titulos_hecho, precio, importe, liquidacion, contraparte, id_estatus, isin, contrato,"
                + "secondary_exec_id, exec_id, F11_ClOrdID, fecha_recepcion, fecha_sentra)"
                    + " values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120),convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120))";

                  // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);


                  for(int counter =0; counter< array1.size();counter++){
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (1, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (2, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }

                      // change emisora and serie to 48 with bd
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("49=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (3, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }

                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("447=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (4, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("54=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (5, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("32=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (6, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("31=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (7, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("381=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (8, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("63=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (9, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("448=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (10, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("150=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (11, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("48=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (12, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 2).equals("1=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (13, array1.get(counter).substring(2));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("527=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (14, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("17=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (15, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("11=")){
                          preparedStmt.setString (16, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                          String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);
                            String date2 = date.substring(3,18);
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                            String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                            String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;
                            System.out.println(newfecha1);

                          preparedStmt.setString (17, newfecha1);
                      }
                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                          String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);
                            String date2 = date.substring(3,18);
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                            String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                            String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                            String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;
                            System.out.println(newfecha1);

                          preparedStmt.setString (18, newfecha1);
                      }


                  }

                  // execute the preparedstatement
                  preparedStmt.execute();
        //notifies you that it was completed
        System.out.println("insert complete");
        // loop to check the digits ex. for() array.1get(counter).substring(0,3).equals("23=")

        //error messages
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Put `preparedStmt.execute();` inside your `for`  loop,  or it will only execute once, with the last set of data.

Comment: Have a look at Files.readAllLines(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-
This would simplify your solution a lot.

Comment: After so much trial and error I finally figured it out Berger. I had to put the query, the values, and the prepared statment all inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // process the line.
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Berger's comment, you should create a helper method that takes in the array, prepares the statement, and sets the values. Then, after the for loop in the while loop, call that method with the array. That will execute the prepared statement for each line in your file.

I also recommend setting array1.get(counter) as a local variable, just to make it easier to read.

Comment: I tried making a method but for some reason it would always say that my values were not being declared. I will keep trying because it will really clean up my code.

Comment: You'd be getting errors about values not being declared on objects like con, your database connection. To get around this, make it global variable, something like this:
    public static Connection con;
outside of a method. The value will get set in the main method, and be usable from your helper method.